# MVC4 - after adding new controller, corresponding view is not generated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, controller

I started learning Asp.NET MVC and got stuck pretty immediately. According to all materials I have, after I add controller in MVC project (Template - empty MVC controller), corresponding view should be created, too (folder under Views). 
However, when I do this, nothing happens. Does anybody know what could be the problem? 
And will this cause me a problems in a long run? I guess I could create those files manually, but still would prefer if they were generated...

My system:
Visual Studio Professional 2013, Update 5 
Project: new MVC Web Application, template "Internet Application"

Thank you

Comment: Views are associated with action methods in a controller (not the controller itself). Create a action method, right click on it and click 'Add View'

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I followed this tutoria, but I guess its a bit outdated - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally views aren't created when a new controller is added. Views can be generated with the following methods:

1. Simply right click the method name within any controller and select "Add View"
2. Right click on the controllers folder and select "Scaffold..." which will created a new controller, views and/or DataContext for a specified model.

Answer (score 2):

Other possible way is to add complete path of the view in your controller method which is returning a view.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
 }
```

this method is useful when you have a hierarchy of folders for view files.